# JPA @StoredProcedureParameter type is Java type or JDBC type

Tags: jpa, stored-procedures, parameters

JPA StoredProcedureParameter annotation

https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/StoredProcedureParameter.html

according to the doc, its type is JDBC type.

```
Class   type
        JDBC type of the paramter.
```

Should it be Java type because it is Class (not java.sql.Types.xxx or JDBCType) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the java class of the type which is mapped to JDBC. So you can use all classes which are mappable/usable with JDBC (e.g. java.lang.Double, java.lang.Long, java.lang.Integer, java.lang.String, ...).

Following link gives you an overview of the supported classes by oracles JDBC driver, but it should give you a clue of what you can use as type.
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e16548/apxref.htm#JJDBC28906